# Installers and productbuild on OSX for Mac App Store

Tags: macos, installation, mac-app-store

I have a product that I would like to distribute on the Mac App Store. For context, this is a Qt (5.3) app written in C++ on OSX 10.9 with Xcode 5.1.1. I have two questions:

1) When I use productbuild like such:

```
productbuild --component /path/to/my/Program.app /Applications Product-Installer.pkg
```

I get the Product-Installer.pkg as expected (this took some effort since the man pages made no mention that the bundle has to be signed before this will work) but when I run the installer, I do not see my app in /Applications. Even though the installer says it installed successfully, I am unable to find any evidence that Program.app was installed anywhere on my system. I am wondering if there is something I'm missing, similar to how not signing the bundle caused productbuild to give me a "The component [component] is not a bundle error?

2) My program has configuration files and I'm not sure what the best way is to handle these on install. For example, in the Windows-world, I would just install a config.ini file (for example) into the user's data folder during install. However, the way the docs read regarding Mac Store Apps, my take is that that's really not done...? I'm wondering then if the best way to handle this is to just generate the config.ini upon the first run of the app? How is this typically handled with App Store apps?

Thank you!

Comment: You would probably want to create two questions as the first one is not really related to the second one. I have answered 2) but have no clue about 1)

Answer (score 0):

2) you would install them in the [Application Support directory in your sandbox container](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW15).

Typically the configuration is called User Defaults and implemented with [CFPreferences](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPreferences/CFPreferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000129-SW1)  in plain old C or [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-SW1) with Objective C. You would ship your UserDefaults.plist inside your package/bundle and [register it on each launch of the app](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDCDB) with `registerDefaults:`.